# Generator expressions vs yield

Tags: python, generator, yield, generator-expression

I was watching this video (http://pyvideo.org/video/1758/loop-like-a-native-while-for-iterators-genera) where at the end he talks about how the generator expression is the same as the normal generator way, but that doesn't seem to be the case and other topics that I've read that is generator expression vs yield say there is no difference. However from what I can see using yield will yield back to the for loop each time where the generator expression doesn't. It completes it's task and then goes back to the for loop. **That's could be a fairly big difference in memory usage (depending on what you're looping over) right? Am I right in my thinking?**

```
# generators call yield which will return to the loop it's called in before coming back
def evens(stream):
    for n in stream:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            print("Inside evens")
            yield n

# this is the same as above just a generator expression
def evens2(stream):
    print("Inside evens2")
    return (n for n in stream if n % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: Your `print()` statement is in the wrong place in `evens`. It should be at the start, not in the loop.

Comment: Your generator expression and generator function behave in *exactly the same way* otherwise. Both yield `n` only when iterating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong in your thinking. Your generator expression does **exactly** the same thing as the generator function, with only one difference: you placed the `print()` call in the wrong place. In `evens2` you print *before* the generator expression has been executed, creating a generator object, while in `evens` you print inside the generator function itself.

If this is Python 3 (or you used `from __future__ import print_function`) you could use the `print()` function inside the generator expression too:

```
def evens2(stream):
    return (print('inside evens2') or n for n in stream if n % 2 == 0)
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
def evens(stream):
    for n in stream:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            yield print("Inside evens") or n
```

`print()` always returns `None`, so `print(..) or n` will return `n`. Iteration over either will both print and yield all even `n` values.

Demo:

```
>>> def evens2(stream):
...     return (print('inside evens2') or n for n in stream if n % 2 == 0)
...
>>> def evens(stream):
...     for n in stream:
...         if n % 2 == 0:
...             yield print("Inside evens") or n
...
>>> g1 = evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> g2 = evens2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> g1
<generator object evens at 0x10bbf5938>
>>> g2
<generator object evens2.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x10bbf5570>
>>> next(g1)
Inside evens
2
>>> next(g2)
inside evens2
2
>>> next(g1)
Inside evens
4
>>> next(g2)
inside evens2
4
```

Both calls produce a generator object, and both generator objects print additional information each time you advance them one step with `next()`.

As far as Python is concerned, the two generator objects produce more or less the same bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('(n for n in stream if n % 2 == 0)', '', 'exec').co_consts[0])
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                27 (to 33)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (n)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
             15 BINARY_MODULO
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             19 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        3
             25 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             28 YIELD_VALUE
             29 POP_TOP
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   33 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile('''\
... def evens(stream):
...     for n in stream:
...         if n % 2 == 0:
...             yield n
... ''', '', 'exec').co_consts[0])
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              35 (to 38)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (stream)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                27 (to 37)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (n)

  3          13 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             19 BINARY_MODULO
             20 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             23 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             26 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7

  4          29 LOAD_FAST                1 (n)
             32 YIELD_VALUE
             33 POP_TOP
             34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   37 POP_BLOCK
        >>   38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             41 RETURN_VALUE
```

Both use `FOR_ITER` to loop, `COMPARE_OP` to see if the output of `BINARY_MODULO` is equal to 0 and *both use `YIELD_VALUE` to yield the value of `n`*.

Comment: ty for the explanation. I wasn't sure I could put a print statement there. So generator expressions just hide the yield statement from us.

Comment: @user441521: exactly, just like a list comprehension hides the `list.append()` call from us.